# keycloak: check if old password matches, if so change to another one

Tags: java, keycloak

Java with maven dependency "keycloak-admin-cli"

I have this code:

```
  keycloakService.findUserByEmailOrUsername( user.getKeycloakUsername() )
                    .ifPresent( userRepresentation -> {
                        //Check for old password
                        if ( userRepresentation.getCredentials() != null ) {
                            for (CredentialRepresentation c : userRepresentation.getCredentials()) {
                                if ( CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD.equals( c.getType() ) ) {
                                    if ( userDTO.getOldpassword().equals( c.getValue() ) ) {
                                        //Das alte Passwort stimmt mit dem in der Datenbank überein. Wir können updaten
                                        //Neues Passwort setzen
                                        CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
                                        credential.setType( CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD );
                                        credential.setValue( userDTO.getPassword() );
                                        credential.setTemporary( false );
                                        userRepresentation.setCredentials( Collections.singletonList( credential ) );
                                    } else {
                                        throw new RuntimeException( "Your current password does not match", null );
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } );
```

I checked with the debugger and I get the correct user. "userRepresentation" is not null.
But the credentials of the user are always null.

Also if I only want to set a new password for the user, it does not update:

```
                keycloakService.findUserByEmailOrUsername( user.getKeycloakUsername() )
                    .ifPresent( userRepresentation -> {
                        CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
                        credential.setType( CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD );
                        credential.setValue( userDTO.getPassword() );
                        credential.setTemporary( false );
                        userRepresentation.setCredentials( Collections.singletonList( credential ) );
                    } );
```

I don't get an error message, keycloak just doesn't update.

Can anyone show me an example how I can check the old password and change it to another one? thx

Comment: You want that a user when setting his/her password that keycloak checks if it already a old password that he/she used?

Comment: @dreamcrash No. Before the user can change his password, I would like him to confirm his current password again.

Comment: I am a little bite confused, but ins't this a feature that is provided already by keycloak out of the box?

Comment: yes, if you are using the gui from keycloak. I am using the maven repository "keycloak-admin-ci" to do this programmatically

Comment: @Paul were you able to solve this problem? I also need to check the user's old password in order to set the new one.

Answer (score 3):

For the updating the password use :

```
userRessource.get(userId).resetPassword(credential);
```

see this example : https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/0c136d0b8d339b997928e9bef225f941

But for checking the actual credential, I didn't manage to check if there's one, as you say userRepresentation.getCredentials() is always null, even after reseting a new password.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the UserResource instead of the UserRepresentation.

`userResource.get(userId).credentials()` instead of `userRepresentation.getCredentials()` should work, but it does feel more like a workaround.

As of 7/26/2021 getCredentials keeps always returning null.

Comment: userRepresentation.getGroups and userRepresentation.getRoles return null as well, therefore some clarification of toRepresentation() in Keycloak doc is necessary.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? I also need to check the user's old password in order to set the new one.

Comment: Sadly not. But looking forward to keycloak 20. There should a lot of improvements also regarding this point